# Javascript can clientHeight be used in place of numerical value in equals operators?

Tags: javascript

Can clientHeight be used in place of numerical values in equals operators such as the example I have below?

```
function DOWN() { 
    var mC = document.getElementById("tester");
    var cT = mC.scrollTop;
    var pos = 0;
    var poscB = mC.clientHeight;
    var Ti = setInterval(frame, 15);

function frame() {
    if (pos == poscB){
        clearInterval(Ti);
    } else {
      pos++;
      mC.style.top = pos + 'px';
       }
       }
       }
```

Comment: Absolutely; you're just assigning the value of one variable to another. It's like saying `a = 2; b = a;`. Now `b` equals `2`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I thought it might be, but for some reason this is not working in the page I am attempting, and thought I might have overstepped clientHeight's use.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, clientHeight returns an integer representing the height of the element in pixels that can be used in numerical operations.

> Note: This property will round the value to an integer. If you need a
>   fractional value, use element.getBoundingClientRect().

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight

if you print typeof(mc.clientHeight) to the console, you will see "number"

```
console.log(typeof(mc.clientHeight));
```

In your example:

```
if (pos == cB) {
            clearInterval(Ti);
        } else {
            pos++;
            mC.style.top = pos + 'px';
        }
```

I think you possibly meant:

```
if (pos == poscB) {
            clearInterval(Ti);
        } else {
            pos++;
            mC.style.top = pos + 'px';
        }
```

Unless you defined cB elsewhere in your script that's not in the example

Comment: Yep! Just found that in the console view.  Thanks for the info though.  I am still a novice at this and wasn't 100% sure if I had been using the clientHeight appropriately.  Thanks again!